# Object-To-Clip for Unity Canvas Image Shader

Tags: unity-game-engine, glsl, hlsl, fragment-shader, unity-ui

## The TL;DR

When applying a shader to a `UI.Image` object in a Unity3D canvas, `UNITY_MATRIX_MVP` appears to be relative to the Canvas renderer, and not the Image object itself being drawn.

Is there a way to compute clip-space coordinates of a point in the Image object's local space, and not only relative to the Canvas root?

### The Overview

As a pre-process step for a shader, I'm computing `x_min`, `x_max`, `y_min` and `y_max` of an image quad on screen as they appear in this mockup:

[image]

My basic approach is to manually compute the clip-space positions of the 4 corners using [`UnityObjectToClipPos`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SL-BuiltinFunctions.html) (which just uses the built-in transformation matrix [`UNITY_MATRIX_MVP`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SL-UnityShaderVariables.html)), and then get the min/max values from those.

I have found this to work for `SpriteRenderer` or `MeshRenderer` components, but for `UI.Image` components in a canvas `UNITY_MATRIX_MVP` appears to only be relative to the canvas parent, and not the image object itself, meaning I cannot use it to calculate the positions relative to the image.

## The Details

*You can find the full shader here: https://gist.github.com/JohannesMP/5a74fcc41d77f281a5900021c01f2356*

For a given object-space coordinate [`UnityObjectToClipPos`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SL-BuiltinFunctions.html) is used to first get the homogeneous clip-space coordinate, which is then shifted to be in screen UV space (values ranging from 0 to 1 when visible on screen):

```c
inline float2 ObjToScreenUV(in float3 obj_pos)
{
    float4 clip_pos4d = UnityObjectToClipPos(obj_pos);
    float2 clip_pos2d = clip_pos4d.xy / clip_pos4d.w;
#if UNITY_UV_STARTS_AT_TOP
    return float2(1 + clip_pos2d.x, 1 - clip_pos2d.y) / 2;
#else
    return (1 + clip_pos2d) / 2;
#endif
}
```

---

Since the 4 vertices of a unit quad are trivial to define in object space (just offset by 0.5 on the object-space X/Y axes), the on-screen min/max values can be computed as follows:

```c
inline float4 GetQuadUVBounds()
{
    // 1. Get relative screen position of 4 quad corners
    float2 bl = ObjToScreenUV(float3(-0.5, -0.5, 0));
    float2 tl = ObjToScreenUV(float3(-0.5, 0.5, 0));
    float2 br = ObjToScreenUV(float3(0.5, -0.5, 0));
    float2 tr = ObjToScreenUV(float3(0.5, 0.5, 0));

    // 2. Get min/max of x and y
    float min_x = min(min(bl.x, tl.x), min(br.x, tr.x));
    float max_x = max(max(bl.x, tl.x), max(br.x, tr.x));
    float min_y = min(min(bl.y, tl.y), min(br.y, tr.y));
    float max_y = max(max(bl.y, tl.y), max(br.y, tr.y));

    return float4(min_x, min_y, max_x, max_y);
}
```

*Please note that I am not looking to optimize the min/max logic at this time.*

---

To verify that the min/max values were correctly calculated they can be used for the red and green channel as the object is drawn.

For example, to verify that `x_min` and `y_min` works, the following fragment shader can be used:

```c
half4 frag () : COLOR
{
    // Min is bounds.xy, max is bounds.zw
    float4 bounds = GetQuadUVBounds();
    return float4(bounds.xy, 0, 1);
}
```

Which for `MeshRenderer` quads and `SpriteRenderer` objects results in this:

[image]

- *As `x_min` increases, so does the red channel.*
- *As `y_min` increases, so does the green channel.*

Testing the max values also yields the expected results.

However when testing the same shader on a `UI.Image` component in a canvas, it does not work as expected:

[image]

Despite the `UI.Image` object (which has the shader set as its material) being moved on the screen, its color does not change. However when in the editor scene view the editor camera is moved, then the color *does* change.

This seems to imply that `UnityObjectToClipPos`, and by extension the `UNITY_MATRIX_MVP` matrix it depends on, are in relation to the Canvas Parent object, and not the Image object inside the parent.

## The Question

Am I correct in my assumption that `UNITY_MATRIX_MVP` is relative to the canvas object, and not the Image object being drawn? If so, is there another way to get an MVP matrix specifically for the Image object? Alternatively, are there any other means by which the Clip-space position of a point in the Image's local space could be computed within a shader?

- I'm using Unity 2017.1.2f1
- The `DisableBatching` shader flag is enabled

Comment: The matrix represents the transform of a **renderer**, so a canvas is a renderer and an image isn't. and why not compute the color in vertex shader? the transformed vertex positions are already the bounds of the image.

Comment: The long and short of it is the effect I'm trying to achieve needs to know where within the XY bounds of the visible image the pixel is on the screen, not just where in the UV bounds of the image's local space. Just as an example, using a grabpass and offsetting the sample outward from the center of the image in screen space to achieve a zoom effect. to scale that corretly it's necessary to know where on the screen the image, not just where in the image the pixel is.